# combine two arrays in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following situation in my PHP script:

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
    /* something happens in here */
}
```

And:

```
foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
   if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
      /* something other happens */
   }
}
```

I would like to combine these two `foreach` statements together. 
I've seen a few solutions around here, but nothing really works for me.

**edit: i want to do something like this**

`echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '"> '.   $recent["post_title"] . get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail',  array('class' => 'beitragimg')).' </a>';`

Comment: Define 'combine'. Assuming they're the same length, why not just use `for()`?

Comment: How you exactly want them to be combined?

Comment: Can you explain the correlation between thumbnails and recent posts? How do you intend to combine them?

Comment: ive edited my question for explanation what i want to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of **PHP 5.3.0**, you can use the [**MultipleIterator**<sup>[PHP.net]</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) class for this:

```
$a = new MultipleIterator();
$a->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($recent_posts), 'recent');
$a->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($thumbnails), 'thumbnail');

foreach ($a as $unit) {
    // $unit['recent'] 
    // $unit['thumbnail']
    if (has_post_thumbnail($unit['thumbnail']->ID)) {
        /* something other happens */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please make that example with my variables. its better for me to understand!

Comment: Now that's powerful. Definitely worth knowing. Might be a tad overengineering in this case, but it works.

Comment: @supersize I have adjusted adjusted the code to use your variable names. You could also use `extract($unit)` to be able to use `$recent` and `$thumbnail` directly without manual assignment. Not sure whether I'd do that though.

Comment: it gives me an error with `class MultipleIterator`undefined. Note: im working in wordpress!

Comment: @supersize In that case, your PHP version is too old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map`

```
$a = ['red','yello','green'] ;
$b = ['apple','banna','mango'];

foreach(array_map(null, $a, $b) as $combined) {
    vprintf("%s %s\n", $combined);
}
```

**Output**

```
red apple
yello banna
green mango
```

Answer (score -1):

Guessing you want something similar to this, but it's a bit of a guess depending on the values of your variables.

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $key => $recent ) {
    $thumbnail = $thumbnails[$key];

    if( has_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID ) )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work unless the array is 0-based. If string keys are used, this fails.