# PHP, combine two arrays into a new array

Tags: php

I have two arrays I want to combine. I need to take the values from two arrays by combining them.

My first array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => a
            [2] => 1a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => b
            [2] => 2b
        )
)
```

And this is my second array:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Aye Aye
            [2] => 18
            [3] => Female
            [4] => Yangon
            [5] => a
        )
  [1] => Array
      (
          [1] => Mg Mg
          [2] => 20
          [3] => Male
          [4] => Mandalay
          [5] => b
      )
)
```

I wanna combine like this:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => a
            [2] => 1a
        [3] => Aye Aye
            [4] => 18
            [5] => Female
            [6] => Yangon
            [7] => a
       )
 [1] => Array
      (
            [1] => b
            [2] => 2b
        [3] => Mg Mg
            [4] => 20
            [5] => Male
            [6] => Mandalay
            [7] => b
      )
)
```

I want to combine like that first array[0] and second array[0], and also first array[1] and second array[1].
First array[0][1] and second array[0][5] are always same and then first array[1][1] and second array[1][5] are also.
Please...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I have fixed the formatting in your question (use the "code block" button, CTRL+K or indent 4 spaces to do this), but there is still crucial information missing. Apart from that, people here expect you to show some effort at solving your own problem -- this is not apparent from your question. Please edit the question to address these problems.

Comment: And could someone tells me what kind of combination it is?

Comment: This is too customized, Maybe array_merge_recursive can do the job, but the best choice is to merge each of your array members separately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [combine two arrays in foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043216/combine-two-arrays-in-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking for `array_merge`, or [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/array_merge_recursive)

Perhaps a better fit would be:

```
$result = array();
for($i=0, $j= count($arr1);$i<$j;$i++)
{//standard loop over array
    $result[$i] = array_merge($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
}
```

That should give you what you need. But please, do look into various `array_*` functions, there's 79 of them in total, odds are that there is one out there, or rather in the core, that suites your needs.

The closest I can get to your desired result, without being *too* silly is this:

```
$result = array();
for($i=0, $j= count($arr1);$i<$j;$i++)
{//standard loop over array
    unset($arr2[$i][3]);
    $arr2[$i] = array_filter($arr2[$i], 'is_string');//gets rid of all the numbers
    $result[$i] = array_unique(array_merge($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]));
}
```

This outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "1a"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Aye Aye"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Female"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "2b"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Mg Mg"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Male"
  }
}
```

Comment: array_merge or array_merge_recursive can not solve my problem. I have been using it. :(

Comment: @Jenny: what about the snippet I've posted? Or do you only want to preserve those values from the second array that _aren't_ numeric? if so `array_filter` and `array_map` spring to mind. Also `array_unique` might come in handy, or `array_walk`... not to mention `list`. There's literally tens of ways to go about this

Comment: Thank you so much! That can solve my worries!

Comment: @Jenny, if the values like `Mandalay` (I assume cities) are always going to be the 4th element in the second array, a simple `unset($arr2[$i][3])` gets rid of those. Be aware that relying on hard-coded quick-fixes like that isn't good practice at all

Answer (score 0):

**From the PHPDocs**

```
<?php
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
$ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

(or)

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: better link the manual in a comment instead of planting code. Planting code is most often only educating new users to help-vampiring.